# reading a text file in C++ displays no output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, text-files

I am very new to C++  i have this code which is supposed to print the text file in Task1 but it displays nothing and it gives me no output. and the text file contains "1 2 3 4" for an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    string line ;
    std::fstream myfile("D:\\Task1.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    getline( myfile, line );
    //cout<<line.length();
    while( getline( myfile, line ) )
    {
        for (int i=0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            cout<<line[i];
            //if (line[i] ...) // look at each character and process it accordingly
        }
    }

    getchar();
}
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: you are consuming the first line without printing it. Also: make sure you actually successfully opened the file.

Comment: i don't get it? how can i do this?

Comment: I tested your code. it works well. would you put your file here too. is it's address correct?

Comment: @BehnamSafari should i place the text file in my project?

Comment: no, just make sure you have `Task1.txt` in `D:/` and it is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple issue with your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    string line ;
    std::fstream myfile("D:\\Task1.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    getline( myfile, line ); // That's the problematic line!
    //cout<<line.length();
    while( getline( myfile, line ) ) // first line lost here
    ...
```

You read the first (and presumably only line) of the file and simply discard it, because you enter the while loop immediately afterwards.

Fix: Remove the line `getline( myfile, line );` that precedes the while loop.

You should also check that the file actually exists (there may be a typo in the filename!):

```
std::fstream myfile("D:\\Task1.txt", std::ios_base::in);
if ( !myfile )
{
   std::cerr << "File does not exist!\n";
   return 1;
}
```

If you aren't planning to use the fstream for output as well, just replace

```
std::fstream myfile("D:\\Task1.txt", std::ios_base::in);
```

by

```
std::ifstream myfile("D:\\Task1.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Better You use ifstream for reading.
Check always an ifstream, whether the open was successful or not.

```
std::ifstream myfile("D:\\Task1.txt");
if( !myfile.is_open() ) {
    cerr << "error open file\n";
    // return or break
}
```

If You want to read numbers, so read numbers

```
for( int number; myfile >> number; ) {
    cout << number << endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::ios_base::in` is not binary mode, it's input mode. But the OP should probably just use an `std::ifstream`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! too less sleep tonight.
I change my code to ifstream

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring first line by reading and do not outputting it.

```
string line ;
ifstream myfile("D:\\Task1.txt");

while(getline(myfile, line))
{
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Extra:

- You don't need to use std namespace if you are using "using namespace std".
- You can use ifstream to read-only.

Answer (score -1):

you need to flush the cout if you want the output printed. Change this line:

`cout<<line[i] << std::endl;`

and you will have the chars printed in a column

Comment: Flushing is not necessary. Eventually, the system will initiate the flush itself.

Comment: Flushing is always necessary, you can not expect that the system will do it, because your program could reach the end and nothing be printed. That is the first reason you can deduce from the code presented, and if it is not, then you could talk about problems with the file

Comment: I don't know of _any_ OS / terminal configuration that doesn't flush on program exit. Can you please name one?

Comment: Only with a succesfull exit the flush will be done, I will say it again, is not a good practice let the flushing to the system.

Comment: So flushing is only necessary for debugging, ok moving on: This still isn't remotely related to the bug in the code.

Answer (score -1):

How many lines you have in text file?
You call `getline` twice before you start printing output. If you have only one line you'll get empty string ;)

Also I don't think your while condition is proper. [Getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) won't return anything useful anyway (it returns istream). If it approach end of file it'll simply rise error flag.

You should do it like that:

```
while (! myfile.eof() )
{
  // do some reading & printing
}
```

Also, please, remember to close your file via myfile.close().

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, the condition is correct. The stream will convert to a boolean indicating an extraction that failed or succeeded.

Comment: getline returns the most useful thing ever: the reference to the istream. Checking that in the condition indicates that the istream is in a meaningful state.

Comment: Manually closing the stream is also unnecessary.

Comment: Can you tell my why it's unnecessary?

Comment: @Konrad'Zegis' the destructor of `fstream` is guaranteed to call `close`.